# How to get inner key in map

Tags: java, collections

I want to get inner value of map. Here is the map.

```
{
  "CUADO3": [
    {
      "C_E": 101,
      "DESCRIPCION": "zz",
      "N_M": 385.19,
      "N_A": 37.45,
      "MS_M": 62.2,
      "MES": 16.42,
      "ME": 79.91,
      "MEF": 3.16
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my java code

```
Map<String,Object> map = dao.getVlaues();
```

IF I want to get with key I can Call Like

```
Object cua = map.get("CUADO3");
```

But I need inside of `CUADO3` C_E I need How Can I get `C_E` from map.

Comment: if CUADO3 contains map then cua.get("C_E");

Comment: @santoshgore cua is not a map to cua.get("C_E");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about the structure then you can cast the object to desired List and Map classes like below and fetch the internal map, then get any desired value from internal map.

```
Map<String,Object> map = dao.getVlaues();
List<Map> listOfMap = (List<Map>)map.get("CUADO3");
Map internalMap = listOfMap.get(0);
System.out.println(internalMap.get("C_E"));
```